# Visualising batch transform model monitoring results within aws sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I've set up a model and run regular batch transforms on it. Data capture is enabled and there is a data quality monitoring schedule that runs every hour. The problem I have is linking the results of the data quality monitor to the model and viewing it within sagemaker. Right now all the examples suggest using a notebook to view the results of a data quality monitor for batch transforms.

- Can we visualise the results within sagemaker like data monitoring on real time endpoints? All examples suggest using a notebook to visualise the results. I don't want to keep running a notebook every time to visualise results.
- Can we link the data quality schedule to model for batch transform jobs? Right now the monitoring jobs take batch transform output as input and are not linked to the model in any way.

The work around I have come up is using a lambda instead of the notebook to serve a static page with results so that it could be easily accessed without having to run a notebook every time.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my recommended approach.

1. Keep storing the metrics in CloudWatch Metrics.
2. When visualization is needed, call CloudWatch's GetMetricWidgetImage API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricWidgetImage.html
   ) to get graph image about the metrics.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).